# What is a counterparty risk trading desk

Tags: risk, trading, counterparty-risk

Can someone explains what does the above mentioned desk do?

What are their responsibilities and how do they manage them, where do they fit into the rest of the organization?

Comment: Welcome Quant SE. I vote to close this question because job and career questions are off-topic. See https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It is the desk responsible for evaluating scenarios corresponding to the action of counterparties (to existing contracts) failing. Their job is risk assessment and risk mitigation via strategies such as market hedging execution, or new business targeting.

Comment: @Attack68 Great answer, could you add it as one?

Comment: @attack68 Thanks for the reply. Would you recommend any reading materials? I come from an engineering background. I have already started looking at derivatives pricing, stochastic calculus since 3 months back so I have some background. I am hoping to learn enough for the interview which is in 3 days.

Comment: The XVA Challenge by Gregory

Comment: You will want to understand CVA (credit valuation adjustments) and related "XVA". The desk would calculate and keep track of these adjustments for each of a bank's counterparties. +1 for any if several books by Gregory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the desk responsible for evaluating scenarios corresponding to the action of counterparties (to existing contracts) failing. Their job is risk assessment and risk mitigation via strategies such as market hedging execution, or new business targeting.

Rather than a "traditional" desk responsible for trading a suite of products (say a bond trading desk trades bonds attempts to ensure that the risk of the portfolio with respect to bond prices is well managed, appropriately sized and positioned favourably) a counterparty risk trading desk manages monetary exposure to counterparties aggregated over many of the sub suites of products, e.g IRS, FXswaps, Equity Swaps, Loans, Cross Currency Swaps, TRS, Options, etc.